# Sql Server create dynamic jobs

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, jobs, job-scheduling

I have to create schedules and if the next run time for the schedules is within the next 15 minutes, I have to create a job for the schedule and  run it .

I know there is a next_run_time field in the sysjobschedules but, Is there a way to get the next_run_time value using only schedules without creating jobs for the schedules?

I created the schedules using **sp_add_schedule** , and wanted to know if there's anyway to get the next scheduled date/time for the schedule  without creating a job for it so I can create the job dynamically  based on the next run date/time values

Comment: Are we talking about SQL Agent jobs?

Comment: How would you propose creating a job schedule with no job? This sounds like a classic xy problem to me. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @Dave.Gugg OP mentions `sysjobschedules` so it must be SQLAgent jobs. But the meaning of question is escaping m.

Comment: @SeanLange - with sp_add_schedule

Comment: @BenThul true you can create a schedule but it has 0 for next_run_date and next_run_time. The schedule has no meaning until a job is attached to it. As such it is no better than no schedule for the OPs question.

Comment: @SeanLange - the question is not an unreasonable one. That is, a schedule describes a recurrence. Wanting to know "what is the next time that that recurrence describes?" seems fair to me. That said, by the way that SQL Server implements it it does not look like there's an easy way to do that.

Comment: @BenThul agreed. It still has the sound of a solution not best suited to the situation at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a schedule without a job.   A schedule is the child of its job.

Comment: That's not true. On my system, I just created a schedule with no job using sp_add_schedule. Jobs:Schedules is n:m where either n or m can be 0.